# IOS react-navigation: screen not rerendered with TabNavigator

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

There are screens Home and New. Home displays a list of data stored in a db. New writes to db. Home screen should remount to display new data when user navigates to it but doesn't. Is this expected behavior, and is there a simple fix?

Home Screen:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home',
};

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    realm = new Realm({schema: [Case]});
    this.state = {
        cases: realm.objects('Case'),
    }
};

render() {
    const listItems = this.state.cases.map((data, index) =>
        <View style={Styles.listItem}>
            <Text key={index}>
                {data.name}
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
    return (
        <View>
            <ScrollView>
                { listItems }
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Routing Configs:

```
const MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator({
Home: { screen: Home },
New: { screen: NewCase },
});

const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: MainScreenNavigator },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SimpleApp', () => SimpleApp);
```